# Why is Intellij Idea's font rendering worse with JDK 1.8 vs 1.6

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, fonts

I have Intellij Idea 14 Ultimate on Mac OS X. With the default `1.6` JDK packaged with it, the fonts look great. However, upon updating the `Info.plist` to use the 1.8 JDK installed on my machine, the fonts look horrible. See screenshots for details.

Intellij Idea 14 font rendering with JDK 1.6 -

[image: Intellij Idea 14 font rendering with JDK 1.6]

Intellij Idea 14 font rendering with JDK 1.8 -

[image: Intellij Idea 14 font rendering with JDK 1.8]

Answer (score 5):

The Java 6 implementation was provided by Apple and used Quartz for font rendering and UI display. The Quartz-based implementation was never open-sourced, so newer versions of Java on Mac supplied by Oracle use a different rendering infrastructure based on OpenGL with a custom font renderer. That's why the rendering is different, and is unlikely to ever become the same.

Quartz also applies a level of gamma correction to the UI, which also explains why your first screenshot is brighter than your second one.

(Note that I don't see anything on your second screenshot which could be called "horrible".)